# set value of all input textboxes with class to '0'

Tags: javascript

After a form submit in MVC C#, I would like a way in JavaScript (not jQuery) to reset the values of all textboxes on the page with class="orderQuantity" to the value of "0". I'm thinking something like:

```
var tObj = getElementsByClassName('orderQuantity');
for(var i = 0; i < tObj.length; i++){
    tObj[i].value='0';}
```

The code above isn't working, hoping you guys can help

Comment: user1823: lol, I sure do :) However, it is still not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `document.getElementsByClassName`. Thus, try the following:

```js
function change(){
    var tObj = document.getElementsByClassName('orderQuantity');
    for(var i = 0; i < tObj.length; i++){
        tObj[i].value='0';
    }
}
```

```html
<input class="orderQuantity" value="foo">
<input class="orderQuantity" value="bar">
<input class="orderQuantity" value="javascript">
<input class="orderQuantity" value="foobar">
<input class="orderQuantity" value="stackoverflow"><br>
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

Comment: Thank you user1823, you're awesome. Putting it in a function did it (I was adding concatenated inline, my syntax must have been funky...that, and the document inclusion).

Comment: Alternatively: `document.querySelectorAll('.orderQuantity');`

Answer (score -1):

You could achieve this by the following method as well.

**HTML Code**

```
<input class="orderQuantity" value="foo">
<input class="orderQuantity" value="bar">
<input class="orderQuantity" value="javascript">
<input class="orderQuantity" value="foobar">
<input class="orderQuantity" value="stackoverflow"><br>
<button onclick="change()">Change</button>
```

**Javascript Code**

```
function change()
{
    $(".ItemRate").val(0);
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because question specifically mentions no jQuery.

Answer (score -2):

use jquery in order to get the class

```
var tObj = $('.orderQuantity');

for(var i = 0; i < tObj.length; i++){
    tObj[i].value='0';}
```

http://fiddle.jshell.net/v4q7pkLn/

Comment: *"Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected."* Also, suggesting to use jQuery only to find elements by class name is completely overkill. If you are suggesting jQuery, then at least do it properly: `$('.orderQuantity').val('0')`.

Comment: Thank you Santiago, your answer would be good if jQuery were added; however, this is for a mobile app that has to be streamlined for ultra-thin clients and therefore does not include jQuery